# Set keydown to function with jquery not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, keydown

basicly i need my page to respond to left and right arrow keys. so trying to have the body tag trigger an event- got it working in chrome etc, will do nothing in firefox- tried googling and after 50 different results still no dice. anyone got any ideas?

heres what i have that works with chrome-

body tag calls this script

`$(document).ready(adjust());`

------------------the javascript

```
function adjust(){
 $("body").keydown(function(){arrowKey(event.keyCode);});
}

function arrowKey(k){
alert(k);
    if (k==37)
        alert("Left");
    else if (k==39)
        alert("Right");
    else if (k==32)
        alert("space");
}
```

ive replaced methods with alerts in the function for testing purpose but i need to be able to call different functions based on which arrow is pressed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it works in chrome even without the "event" because event is a keyword in chrome and it is filled with the last triggered event.

The reason it doesn't work in firefox is because you should assign the event like this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event){arrowKey(event.keyCode);});
```

For some reason "body" does not accept the keydown event. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("body").keydown(function( ){arrowKey(event.keyCode);});
                           ^
```

`event` is missing perhaps

```
$("body").keydown(function(event){arrowKey(event.keyCode);});
```

On [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tgVP4/1/).

Comment: well got it to call an alert in firefox by changing it to $("html") instead of "body"- but it just created a whole bunch of new problems... sigh, thanks

Comment: use $(document) instead of $("body")

Comment: @omerkirk perhaps that would be better.

Answer (score -1):

Ok Why You don't use JavaScript

```
window.body.onkeydown=function(evt)
{
arrowKey(evt.keyCode);
}
```